# Remote JNDI + Spring Boot + WebLogic, How to specify the context from the application.property?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am developing a project in Spring Boot and Spring Data, I want to use JNDI from WebLogic remote server.

I have an old example which does not use Spring, It does it of the follow way:

```
DataSource pool = null; Hashtable ht = null;
ht = new Hashtable( );
ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"t3://192.151.120.180:7003,192.151.121.180:7005");
ht.put(weblogic.jndi.WLContext.ENABLE_SERVER_AFFINITY, "true");
env =  new InitialContext(ht);
pool = (DataSource) env.lookup("jdbc.conPesos");
```

I want to do the same connection, but from `application.property` file (or `application.yml` file) with Spring Boot .

It is my code:

```
 spring:
     datasource:
         driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
         url: t3://192.151.120.180:7003
         jndi-name: java:/comp/env/jdbc/conPesos
```

I got the mistake:

> Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path
>   resource [----]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
>   Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method
>   'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException:
>   Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name
>   'java:/comp/env/jdbc/conPesos'; nested exception is
>   javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in
>   environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an
>   application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial

To resolve the mistake, I created a `@configuration` class with the follow code:

```
 @Bean public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
     Context ctx ;
     DataSource dataSource;
     Hashtable<String, String> ht;
     NamedParameterJdbcTemplate np;

     ht = new Hashtable<>();
     ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
     ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://192.151.120.180:7003");
     ht.put(weblogic.jndi.WLContext.ENABLE_SERVER_AFFINITY, "true");
     ctx = new InitialContext(ht);

     dataSource=(DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc.conPesos");
     return dataSource; }
```

Also I had to write `SpringBootApplication(exclude = JmxAutoConfiguration.class)` in the main class. It works fine, however I would like to do it from the `application.property` file, but I do not know how I can add the  INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY property in that file.

Does someone know it?

Comment: The error is telling you what to do. `javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file: java.naming.factory.initial`. Specify a system parameter (-D` with the settings you now have in the `HashTable`).

Comment: Ok, but i want to do it from the application.yml file. Like in this link: https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/1ad40f9 . I should not write nothing code in Java, however I do not know the way to do it. The datasource data sintaxis is no correct.

Comment: Where do I say you have to write java? You need to put system properties in place.

Comment: Hi did you able to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Beware to use the following annotation parameter, otherwise the WebLogic-managed datasource will be stopped by Spring Boot on the first stop/undeploy of your application, and will not be restarted afterwards until the WebLogic Server(JVM) is restarted :

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "")
```

which will raise an exception as follows :

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: DataSource jdbc/myDatasource is not active
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.WLDataSourceImpl.checkActive(WLDataSourceImpl.java:596)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.WLDataSourceImpl.getConnectionInternal(WLDataSourceImpl.java:617)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.WLDataSourceImpl.getConnection(WLDataSourceImpl.java:611)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.WLDataSourceImpl.getConnection(WLDataSourceImpl.java:604)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
```

Comment: This was exactly my problem after going from SpringBoot 2.3.5 to Spring Boot 2.5.1 in Weblogic 12.  Your fix is so appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I can solve the problem from a class configuration (
I was not able to do it from application.property file). With the follows code:

```
@Bean(name = "conProcesosDS")
    public DataSource dataSourceProcesos() throws NamingException {
        Context ctx;
        DataSource dataSource;
        Hashtable<String, String> ht;

        ht = new Hashtable<>();
        ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://192.151.120.180:7003");
        ht.put(weblogic.jndi.WLContext.ENABLE_SERVER_AFFINITY, "true");
        ctx = new InitialContext(ht);

        dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc.conPesos");
        return dataSource;
    }
```

You have to add the library of **wlfullclient-10.1.0.1.jar**. Maven does not have the library, you must search it in the web and add it to project. (I created a local repository with nexus).

I also added the annotation @SpringBootApplication(exclude = JmxAutoConfiguration.class) in the main class. Like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = JmxAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Aplicacion extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        SpringApplication.run(Aplicacion.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Aplicacion.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: too bad hashtable is deprecated...would it there an alternative?